# filling UITableView with JSON data won't work

Tags: ios, json, ios5, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I'm having this problem. I'm trying to build an UITableView with data from a JSON Dictionary made with NSJSONSerialization. I have no idea where to start. i've been trying for 3 days but silo have achieved nothing. This is the code i've came up with:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kJsonURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://rs-hosting.nl/panel/serverstatus_json.php"]

#import "ViewController.h"



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kJsonURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSDictionary *clients = [json objectForKey:@"announcements"];
    NSArray *announcements = [clients objectForKey:@"announcement"];
    NSDictionary* announcement = [announcements objectAtIndex:1];

}
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

I'm able to display content in a label on a single view in a label but i have no clue how to het all the data in the json to a table. Can someone please healp me out?

SDK: 5.1
OSX: 10.7.3
XCODE: 4.3.1

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your data somewhere (keeping that NSDictionary with the whole json file is fine for a start) and then add a UITableView, set it up to point its data source to your class and then implement the [UITableViewDataSource methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) as outlined.

The UITableView will then request data from these methods as it fills in the table. The only two required methods are `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so start with those two and get the data displaying on the table before doing any other customization.

Comment: by storeing it somewhere else you mean like defineing a dictionary instaande variable?

Answer (score 1):

after getting data in NSDictionary, save it in NSArray filled with NSString objects that u want to show and then call the function [Tableview reloadData]; in you ViewDidLoad function and ur good to go.